# Is it possible to equip elytra using commands on Minecraft Pocket edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im on Pocket edition trying to make a puzzle map and I'm trying to equip elytra using commands and I can't figure it out

Comment: What command have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `/replaceitem entity <target> slot.armor.chest 0 elytra`

- `replaceitem entity`: replace/give/take an item from an inventory slot of an entity
- `<target>`: A player name or a [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selectors). Substitute this with whichever you are using, without the `<>`s.
- `slot.armor.chest`: References the chest armour slot.
- `0`: This number is used to specify which specific slot is to be replaced. For this specific command (changing the chestplate slot) this can be almost any number, but for either editing blocks or the main inventory this is necessary.
- `elytra`: The new item.